# Writing preprocessed output CSV to S3 from Scikit Learn image on Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

My problem: writing out a CSV file to S3 from inside a Sagemaker SKLearn image. I know how to write CSVs to S3 from a notebook - that is working fine. It's within the docker image that I'm unable to get it to work.

This is a preprocessing.py script called as an entry_point parameter to the SKLearn estimator. The purpose is to pre-process the data prior to running an inference. It's the first step in my inference pipeline.

**Everything is working as expected in my preprocessing script, except outputting the file at the end**.

1. Attempt #1 - this **produces a CSV file that has strange binary-looking data at the beginning and end of the file** (before the first cell and after the last cell of the CSV). It's almost a valid CSV but not quite. *See the image at the end.*

```
def write_joblib(file, path):
    s3_bucket, s3_key = path.split('/')[2], path.split('/')[3:]
    s3_key = '/'.join(s3_key)
    with BytesIO() as f:
        joblib.dump(file, f)
        f.seek(0)
        boto3.client("s3").upload_fileobj(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key, Fileobj=f)
    
predictors_csv = predictors_df.to_csv(index = False)
write_joblib(predictors_csv, predictors_s3_uri)
```

2. Attempt #2 - I used StringIO rather than BytesIO. However, this produced a zero-byte file on S3.
3. Attempt #3 - I tried boto3.client('s3').put_object(...) but got ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

I believe I am almost there with Attempt #1 above. I assume it's an encoding issue. If I can fix the structure of the CSV file to remove the non-text characters at the start it will be working. A screenshot of the CSV in a Notepad++ is below.

[Notice the non-character text at the start of the CSV file below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHMx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. This works within an SKLearn estimator container. I assume it will work inside any inbuilt fit/tranform container for writing a CSV to S3 directly.

The use case is writing out the results of pre-processing for model featurization, vectorization, dimensionality reduction etc. This would occur prior to model inference as the first step in an Inference Pipeline.

```
def write_text_file_to_s3(file_string, path):

    s3_bucket, s3_key = path.split('/')[2], path.split('/')[3:]
    s3_key = '/'.join(s3_key)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Object(s3_bucket, s3_key).put(Body=file_string)

predictors_csv = predictors_df.to_csv(index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
write_text_file_to_s3(predictors_csv, predictors_s3_uri)
```